# How to add favicon.ico on beego?

Tags: go, beego

my routers/default.go, I'm trying to use the original Go solution, but failed, this code can't compiled. I don't know how to replace the router with faviconHandler:

```
func faviconHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {                                                                                                                                 
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "static/img/favicon.ico")                                                                                                                                        
}                                                                                                                                                                                             
func init() {                                                                                                                                                                                 
        beego.Router("/", &controllers.MainController{})                                                                                                                                      
        beego.Router("/favicon.ico", faviconHandler)  // this doesn't work                 
}
```

Comment: Failed _how_ (404 error page, panic etc.)?

Comment: Q1:can't compile; Q2:I don't know how to plugin suitable handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found there is at least one method: embedded into index.tpl.

```
bee new newapp
cd $GOPATH/src/newapp
bee run  # you will see the favicon of a bee.
```

Modify the embedded text in $GOPATH/src/view/index.tpl to yours, here is a linux script

```
cd views
# assume you have put the favicon.ico in this directory
base64 -w0 favicon.ico > favicon.b64
cp index.tpl index.tpl.old
sed 's/base64,.*"/base64,\n"/' index.tpl.old | sed '7r favicon.b64' > index.tpl
# rm favicon.ico favicon.b64  index.tpl.old # remove the temp file
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your favicon.ico file at ./static/ directory

Check this https://beego.me/docs/quickstart/static.md

Comment: As I know favicon.ico should put in / otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Yeah, the request url for favicon.ico is /favicon.ico.

I mean put your favicon.ico in your static files directory. And "static" is set as default by beego